# Forge cannot deploy to Digital Ocean (Permission denied) Public key

Tags: laravel, ssh, digital-ocean, forge

I have looked and tried again and again and need to reach out for help.

I can push from my local machine to Gitlab no problem.

But when Forge attempts to deploy it responds with an Error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Key = xxx
```

I can ssh into the server with forge@my-ip and cd /.ssh/ and cat authorized_keys. My public key @ /Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub is there and the forge key from the error message is on there on the forge user account too.

When I log in to Digital Ocean, my id_rsa.pub is there

On Forge, my server, ssh keys, my id_rsa.pub is there

On Gitlab, my id_rsa.pub is there

Can someone suggest what's wrong? Would really appreciate it! This was my first Laravel app in production which has been lying idle for a while and I am now putting back into production with an upgrade from 5.3 to 5.4 so maybe it could be some Laravel config issue?

Comment: What is the command you used to deploy?

Comment: git push, the code is there on gitlab. Maybe try push - all?

Comment: try with `GIT_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"` and post the results.